# Accessing custom Swift structs directly like a String, without having to use "struct.property" notation

Tags: swift

I'm not exactly sure how to describe this one but I'm trying to create a Swift struct that can be accessed like a standard String. I think it will be easier to explain with a code example.

Let's say that we have the following as a struct:

```
struct MultilangString {
    let dictionary:[String:String]

    init(_ dict:[String:String]){
        self.dictionary = dict
    }

    func getLocalString() -> String {
        let lang:String = MultilangString.getCurrentLocale()

        if let stringLocale = self.dictionary[lang]{
            return stringLocale
        } else {
            return "Error while getting localized string."
        }
    }
    static func getCurrentLocale() -> String {
        // code to get current device locale
    }
}
```

And we use it like:

```
let name = MultilangString(["en":"First name","fr":"Prénom"])

print(name.getLocalString())
```

Is there a way, a special(magic) getter etc. to declare a struct that is accessible like a standard String? For example print(name) should be the same as print(name.getLocalString())

Comment: Looks like `CustomStringConvertible` is what you are looking for. You just need to implement your object description property. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible

Comment: What do you mean *accessible like a standard String*?

Comment: Are you going to create a variable or property for each string/word that has a translation? Shouldn't it be one dictionary with all the words instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
extension MultilangString: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "your custom string here after compute"
    }
}

print(name) // Prints - your custom string here after compute
```